# How to move variables from one Activity to another in android studio

Tags: android, android-intent

I’m trying to move three doubles from one `Activity` to another but it’s not working for me.
I’ve tried to use `Intent.putExtra()` but it’s said that it can’t do it. Anybody can help me please?
I’ve really tried a lot but I don’t know how to do it. I’m new to programming.

Answer (score 0):

When launching the second activity, use something to the effect of,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("key1", double1);
intent.putExtra("key2", double2);
intent.putExtra("key3", double3);
```

Then, in the onCreate() method of your second activity, extract them as follows:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
double double1 = intent.getDoubleExtra("key1", 0.0);
double double2 = intent.getDoubleExtra("key2", 0.0);
double double3 = intent.getDoubleExtra("key3", 0.0);
```

Comment: Thanks, but the code of the second page is not working.

Comment: You're right, I missed a parameter.  I edited the answer to fix that.